# VB6: Error AxtiveX component can't create object

Tags: vb6, autocad

I think this is old question but I need to detail my case.

I use the command Set objAcad = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application") to call AutoCAD and get error as above.

But this command worked well when PC has admin user but for some security reasons, this right is removed. User only use standard (domain) user.

Only AutoCAD 2006,2007,2008,2009 got this issue. It works on AutoCAD 2015(even domain user).
I used win7 64bit.

Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty string instead of nothing as the first parameter, i.e.

```
Set objAcad = GetObject("", "AutoCAD.Application")
```

According to [this reference](http://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson10/p7.html) there is a difference.  In your example, if an instance does not already exist, it will return an error, but with the empty string, it will create a new instance (like CreateObject()

Comment: Hi Bill,

Thanks for your support.

But I got the error:

AutoCAD LT Application has stopped working.

I wonder about the domain user and admin user. How does it effect to this command or AutoCAD (because it worked with admin user) ?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't say it was LT. You can't use this on AutoCAD LT.

Comment: Hi reckface,

Thanks for your info.
But these AutoCAD LT it worked several years ago with local admin right. It just doesn't work when I take out the local admin right and provide users the domain user.

When user click to autoCAD icon, a popup appear to user login with local admin  for autoCAD software only then it work well.

But the issue when VB6 export drawing to autoCAD, it open autoCAD  with above command then get the error. I'm ready provide the local admin for VB6 open autoCAD but i can't.


Thanks,
Hung